# "show_signal_msg: N callbacks suppressed" then pegged at 100% and machine unresponsive

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, server-crashes

This happened on an Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit DigitalOcean Droplet:

```
Apr 22 02:17:02 localhost CRON[32514]: (root) CMD ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly) 
Apr 22 03:16:59 localhost kernel: [211877.884132] show_signal_msg: 12 callbacks suppressed 
Apr 22 03:16:59 localhost kernel: [211877.884140] python[2376]: segfault at 24 ip 00000000004c278f sp 00007fbad163caa0 error 6 in python2.7[400000+2bd000]
```

Right around 3:16 AM, the CPU spiked up to 100%, and the machine became unresponsive to ping, SSH and (remote) console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlNHA.png

How could the "callback suppressed" throttling appear *before* the first segfault?

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L727

In general, how could a few segfaults cause the kernel to lock up? The offending process was in 'while :; do python script.py; sleep 1; done' (NOTE sleep), was running with 'nice 10' and had an increased oom_adj so that the kernel would kill it first:

```
open('/proc/self/oom_adj', 'w').write('10')
os.nice(10)
```

Comment: If 12 callbacks from `show_signal_msg` were suppressed that means that something segfaulted 13 times in a row. Do you have coredumps enabled on that box?

Comment: `ulimit -c` is 0. You would suggest setting it to `unlimited`? How would I use the core dumps to figure out why the machine locks up?

Comment: No, I just suggested that "unresponsiveness" can be connected to codedumps being written to disk.

Comment: Ah, I doubt it - the CPU was pegged at 100% for several hours: http://imgur.com/hMSH5SV.png

Answer (score -1):

So far looks like this kernel bug:

http://blog.nitrous.io/2014/03/10/stability-and-a-linux-oom-killer-bug.html

Comment: That is the reason one should not answer questions with links. Now I have no idea what that killer bug is :(

Comment: @douglaslps: Thankfully, we have the Internet Archive on our side! https://web.archive.org/web/20160310202252/https://community.nitrous.io/posts/stability-and-a-linux-oom-killer-bug

Comment: Sorry about that @douglaslps.